# SQL to query the id with the most count in a table

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have these tables here:

[image]

and I want to query the **store ID with the most purchases** in a specific month (any month).
I came up with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_id FROM (SELECT store_id, purchase_date FROM purchase where purchase_date >= '2021-04-01' AND purchase_date <= '2021-04-30'

SELECT DISTINCT store)
```

I am still starting in SQL and I can't seem to move from here.

Comment: `select x.store_id, sum(x.total) total from (
 select p.store_id, (pi.price*pi.quantity) total from purchase_item pi
 left join purchase p
 on pi.purchase_id=p.id
 where p.purchase_date between '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-30'
) x
group by x.store_id
order by total desc limit 1;`
Assuming most purchases means highest sale and not the number of sales and date shall not be text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that most purchases means highest sales and not the number of sales and purchase_date is not text but of type date:

```
select x.store_id, sum(x.total) total from (    
   select p.store_id, (pi.price*pi.quantity) total from purchase_item pi
   left join purchase p     on pi.purchase_id=p.id  
   where p.purchase_date between '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-30' 
) x 
group by x.store_id 
order by total desc 
limit 1;
```

If you want to just find store with maximum number of purchases and not the Total value of sales:

```
select p.store_id, count(p.store_id) from purchase p
where p.purchase_date between '2021-04-01' AND '2021-04-30' 
group by p.store_id
order by count(p.store_id) desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select count(store_id) as counted_store,store_id from purchase where MONTH(purchase_date) = '5' GROUP BY counted_store ORDER BY counted_store DESC limit 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).